# Reference .dll method unable to create folder in web server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a reference .dll method which will create folder in SpecialFolder.

So in .aspx.cs, i execute this method but it throw me an exception

```
"Access the ..... is denied"
```

However,if i create it in my web application without using the reference to create, it have no problem.

Anyone know what's the problem and solution?

This is the create directory method definition:

```
string TempPDFPath
            = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),
                Path.Combine("TempPDFStorage", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

                    if (!Directory.Exists(TempPDFPath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(TempPDFPath);
                    }
```

Comment: is that refrence dll in the same folder where the dll of web application? if not make sure that the folder in which the dll is present have enough access rights.

Comment: @Gregory:why i have to stop IIS?

Comment: @VikramShetty, yes,it is in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Site is run under some pool . In pool you can define identity user.
The user that you will define should have strong permissions
[image]

So you need to define user with administrator permissions and to assign this user 
to pool that you virtual directory is run. See the image above

Comment: i don't find .NET4, but only found DefaultAppPool, ReportServer.

Comment: .Net 4 it's a pool that I defined for my website. I posted as example. See under what pool defined your site , define identity for the pool and give to this identity strong permission

Comment: my one is under DefaultAppPool. And the predefined is Network Service. but the problem still exist

Comment: Right , so you need to change it. Define user for server computer with the administrator rights , than in DefaultAppPool click configurable,

Comment: and change it to the user that your defined

Comment: i host it in server,so i should change it to server username and password?

Comment: If you host in server  , you need to set to folder permissions to write . I think its 777 via FTP client . Try to set maybe it will help